# Expand a tree path by sending the internalId as parameter

Tags: extjs, tree, extjs4

Please consider the situation:

1. I'm using Extjs' `tree.Panel` to have some sort of navigation on a page.
2. I have a *list of items* in another portion of the page, whose list items have a unique id that matches the `internalId` of a node in the tree.
3. I wish to bind a click for each *list item* and expand the tree to the node specified by the id on the item.

I intend to use the `expandPath(path)` method from the tree. My question would be: **how can I get the `path` string with just the `internalId`?** Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately function `NodeInterface.getPath` was [vanished](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?133027-Stateful-Trees-in-EXTJS-4) from extjs4. So there is no way to use `expandPath(path)`. But, instead, you can use

```
tree.store.getNodeById('ext-record-23').bubble(function(node){node.expand()});
```

Comment: Thanks Molecule, I'll look into that by Monday.

Comment: That id you're passing, can I pass the internalId?

Comment: Passing internalId worked for me. But I didn't set id for nodes explicitly.