# Extjs 4 treepanel Reload and Expand

Tags: extjs, tree, load, extjs4

I'm using Extjs4 treepanel with Json data.I want reload the treepanel and need expand tree menu to specified node.
I'm using the following code. Please let me know how do this.

```
//Define tree store

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'my_tree.php',
    },

    noCache: false
});

// Treepanel
var treePanel = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    id: 'mytree',
    renderTo: 'tree_div',
    height: 400,
    bodyBorder: false,
    border: false,
    singleExpand: true,
    rootVisible: false,
    store: store,
    useArrows: true
});

//Reload tree
    function reload_tree(){
       var tree_panel = Ext.getCmp('mytree');
        tree_panel.enable();
        tree_panel.getLoader().dataUrl = 'my_tree.php';
       tree_panel.getLoader().load(tree_panel.root);
       //Expand tree node
       tree_panel.getLoader().on('load', function(loader, node){ 
              tree_panel.getNodeById(nodeid).expand();
    //here node id is tree menu nodeid 
   });
   }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reload the tree i think it's simpler to just call

```
treePanel.getStore().load();
```

then you can listen to the load event, so that the data is all fetched and finally from there select the desired node.

```
    treePanel.on("load", function( treeStore, records, successful, operation)){

    var id = 4; // This is the ID of the node that somehow you know in advance
    var node = treeStore.getNodeById(id);

    treePanel.expandPath(node.getPath());
});
```

HTH!

Comment: Thanks for your quick replay.The treepanel is loading fine but its not expanding, In firebug shows the error "node.getPath not a function".

Comment: Oh my bad, sorry the getPath() vanished in ExtJS 4, though you have and alternative way to expand the desired node, please look ate the answer of Molecule Man in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6709106/expand-a-tree-path-by-sending-the-internalid-as-parameter

Comment: humm.. Thanks Byte slave thanks a lot. It's works fine. The node expanding exactly what i'm expecting but it is not selected(style affect). Generally if any treemunu node which is selected have some different selected style. can you help me?

Comment: Previously in Exts2.0 i'm using tree_panel.getNodeById(nodeid).ensureVisible(); 
tree_panel.getNodeById(nodeid).select(); to select node after it expands.

Comment: If you find the index of the record you want to select, you can use var selNodeIndex = 0;
var record = tree_panel.getRootNode().getChildAt(selNodeIndex);
tree.getSelectionModel().select(record); if you can't then, via the store, try to get the record, by id pr something and just pass the record to tree.getSelectionModel().select(record);